# discrete cosine transform implementation differs from library function

Tags: python, image-processing, scipy, signal-processing, fft

I've implemented my own DCT function, but the output differs from scipy's fftpack dct function. I was wondering if anyone knows whether fftpack.dct( ) does any additional transformations, and if so what they are ?
Note: I've tried subtracting 128 from the data but that just changes the colors, not the frequency locations.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import empty,arange,exp,real,imag,pi
from numpy.fft import rfft,irfft
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from  scipy import fftpack

def dct(x):
    N = len(x)
    x2 = empty(2*N,float)
    x2[:N] = x[:]
    x2[N:] = x[::-1]

    X = rfft(x2)
    phi = exp(-1j*pi*arange(N)/(2*N))
    return real(phi*X[:N])

def dct2(x):
    M = x.shape[0]
    N = x.shape[1]
    a = empty([M,N],float)
    X = empty([M,N],float)

    for i in range(M):
        a[i,:] = dct(x[i,:])
    for j in range(N):
        X[:,j] = dct(a[:,j])

    return X
if __name__ == "__main__":

    data = np.array([
        [0,0,0,20,0,0,0],
        [0,0,20,50,20,0,0],
        [0,7,50,90,50,7,0],
        [0,0,20,50,20,0,0],
        [0,0,0,20,0,0,0],
        ])
    
    X = dct2(data)
    plt.matshow(X)
    
    X2 = fftpack.dct(data)
    plt.matshow(X2)
```

data:

[image]

X:

[image]

X2:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `scipy.fftpack.dct` performs the 1D dct transform whereas you implemented the 2d dct transform. To perform the 2D dct using scipy use:

```
X2 = fftpack.dct(fftpack.dct(data, axis=0), axis=1)
```

This should solve your problem, since the resulting matrix using your example will be:
[image]

Which is similar to your implementation up to a constant factor. The constant factor can be controlled using the `norm` argument to the dct, read more [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.fftpack.dct.html)